# Is there a way to create a segue with code

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have two view controllers(Master & Details) embedded into a navigation controller. My controller 2 (Details) is actually build from code exclusively (so no drag and drop of components on the storyboard). In Details I have a button and I want it to trigger an unwind segue when clicked . I can not figure out how to do that if my button is not defined on the storyboard but added with code.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the unwind segue with code by follow these steps:

1. **Specify an Action method in the View Controllers we wish to unwind
   to:**

   ```
   [Action("ToDetailPage:")]
   public void ToDetailPage(UIStoryboardSegue segue)
   {

   }
   ```
2. **Create an unwind segue in Storyboard and set the identifier in its Properties**, like this:
   [image]
3. **Add `PerformSegue` method in the action method of your button which build with code.**

   ```
       private void Button_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           PerformSegue("ToDetail", this);
       }
   ```

   *Notice that the identifier parameter of `PerformSegue` should match the one you input in step 2#.*

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i am looking for .